# T-SQL Getting duplicate rows returned

Tags: t-sql

The following code section is returning multiple columns for a few records.

`SELECT a.ClientID,ltrim(rtrim(c.FirstName)) + ' ' +`

```
case when c.MiddleName <> '' then
ltrim(rtrim(c.MiddleName)) + '. ' 
else '' 
end +

ltrim(rtrim(c.LastName)) as ClientName, a.MISCode, b.Address, b.City, dbo.ClientGetEnrolledPrograms(CONVERT(int,a.ClientID)) as Abbreviation
FROM ClientDetail a
JOIN Address b on(a.PersonID = b.PersonID)
JOIN Person c on(a.PersonID = c.PersonID)
LEFT JOIN ProgramEnrollments d on(d.ClientID = a.ClientID and d.Status = 'Enrolled' and d.HistoricalPKID is null)
LEFT JOIN Program e on(d.ProgramID = e.ProgramID and e.HistoricalPKID is null)
WHERE a.MichiganWorksData=1
```

I've isolated the issue to the ProgramEnrollments table.
This table holds one-to-many relationships where each ClientID can be enrolled in many programs.  So for each program a client is enrolled in, there is a record in the table.

The final result set is therefore returning a row for each row in the ProgramEnrollments table based on these joins.

I presume my join is the issue but I don't see the problem.

Thoughts/Suggestions?

Thanks,

Chuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JOIN is not the issue, it's doing what it's meant to do with a one-to-many relationship

You could use a GROUP BY statement on your query, or alternatively use a sub-select to return DISTINCT values from the ProgramEnrollments/Program tables.

You don't seem to be using data from the ProgramEnrollments or Program tables so are they needed in the query (I presume they are, just thought I'd ask the question).

Comment: You're right.  I just realized that I don't need either of those tables anymore as I am handling them in the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually appear to be using any columns in `ProgramEnrollments` or `Program`, so try removing those 2 JOINs.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Great community here.  Just joined today. Glad I did, I'll be back!